# Area under the curve uing 4 rectangles evaluated at the right hand endpoint

Tags: calculus, area

Approximate the area under the curve $f(x)=3x^2+1$ over the interval $[1,3]$ using 4 rectangles evaluated at the right hand endpoints. Would I do $(3-1)/4=.5$? If so what do I do after that step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sum_{n=1}^{n=2.5}(f(n)*h)$

where $h=0.5$

see the illustration :

[image]

As seen in the graph, the area under the curve is approximated using the sum of areas of the 4 rectangles, where the $length = h$ and $height = f(x)$.

Comment: I don't know what this means, can you explain this?

Comment: @Ben, see the edit and the image

Comment: I thought you had to do this: (1)(.5)+(1.5)(.5)+(2)(.5)+(2.5)(.5)=3.5

Comment: @ben actuall it is $f(1)*0.5 + f(1.5)*0.5 + f(2)*0.5 + f(2.5)*0.5$

Comment: but the answer for the problem is 3.5 correct?

Comment: Or am I wrong @chouaib?

Comment: @Ben: it is very easy to calculate,and yes you are wrong about the result

Comment: is the answer 22.25?

Comment: @Ben I updated the image, and yes $22.25$ is the true answer for this example, but please make sure you understood the method not only got the right answer for the moment, if anything is still not clear let me know

Comment: actually yes, did you get 1,1.5,2,2.5 because n=1 and h is .05?

Comment: @ben : exactly! Now you can try other approximations by changing $h$, try for example $h=0.1$ and see how better it will be. P.S the exact area is $\int_{1}^{3}(3x^2+1)dx = [x^3+x]_1^3 = 28$

Comment: Perfect! And what do you mean by the exact area?

Comment: @Ben: I mean the not-*approximated* area, the real one